# Set a isopend flag in database using laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have many documents in my server and In my database, there is two columns that holds the `username` and `isopene[flag]`. While a user viewing the document I am setting these values in the database. Is there any particular better implementation in Laravel for these kinda scenarios?

Comment: I think you will need to try to explain better what exactly it is you are trying to do so a solution can be more acclimated to your needs. Maybe, if you could share some code or examples that would be more useful to the better assist your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe Pessimistic Locking

The query builder also includes a few functions to help you do "pessimistic locking" on your select statements. To run the statement with a "shared lock", you may use the sharedLock method on a query. A shared lock prevents the selected rows from being modified until your transaction commits:

```
DB::table('users')->where('votes', '>', 100)->sharedLock()->get();
```

Alternatively, you may use the lockForUpdate method. A "for update" lock prevents the rows from being modified or from being selected with another shared lock:

```
DB::table('users')->where('votes', '>', 100)->lockForUpdate()->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#pessimistic-locking